# ValueError when transforming DataFrame to xarray (non-unique MultiIndex)

Tags: python, dataframe, netcdf, python-xarray

I have two ncdf files with one containing lat/lon-coordinates and one with the actual data. Each cell of the coordinate arrays contains an information about lat and lon, respectively. Im trying to get a combined dataset (to be able to work with it), which I also want to subset. Therefore I open both datasets with `xarray.open_dataset()`, transform them to a pandas dataframe and append the data columns to the dataframe with the coordinates. Afterwards I create the subset using `.between()`. I also set lat/lon as new index with `.set_index()`. So far so good. The next step would be transforming the dataframe back to a `xarray` and then write the combined dataset back to ncdf, but when I do the xarray transformation using `.to_xarray()`, I get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot convert a DataFrame with a non-unique MultiIndex
> into xarray

I found a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182042/valueerror-cannot-convert-a-dataframe-with-a-non-unique-multiindex-into-xarray) but the there presented answer doesn't make sense for my case. It isn't possible, that there are duplicate coordinate pairs.

My code looks as follows:

```
import xarray as xr


geo_path = 'PATH/TO/geolocation.nc'
dat_path = 'PATH/TO/data.nc'

# Open datasets
geo_ds = xr.open_dataset(geo_path)
dat_ds = xr.open_dataset(dat_path)

# Transform to dataframe
geo_df = geo_ds.to_dataframe()
dat_df = dat_ds.to_dataframe()

# Add coordinates to the actual data
dat_df['lat'] = geo_df['lat']
dat_df['lon'] = geo_df['lon']


# Create subset
dat_filter = dat_df[(dat_df['lat'].between(60, 71) & dat_df['lon'].between(132, 138))]

# Set new index
dat_filter = dat_filter.set_index(['lat', 'lon'])

# Convert back to xarray
dat_filter.to_xarray()
```

The files can be found [here](https://cloudstore.zih.tu-dresden.de/index.php/s/ddbNXLBGoLgETni) (79.3 mb) and of course any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have 3 dimensions in the data: longitude, latitude and altitude. So you will need the following lines in your code:

```
dat_df['alt'] = geo_df['altitude']

# Set new index
dat_filter = dat_filter.set_index(['lat', 'lon', 'alt'])
```

Comment: The error remains despite adding the lines from your suggestion.

Comment: Xarray requires a single value for each point in space and time. You will need to make them unique